# Objective-C: Determine which file has performed an NSLog

Tags: objective-c, nslog

Say I have 10 different implementation files that are run in an chaotic order, and in each of them I have an `NSLog(@"Log");`, and when I run the program I will get 10 `Log`'s to my console output, but how can I know which one was logged by which file? I'm searching for something like

```
`In someFile1.m: Log`
`In someFile3.m: Log`
`In someFile2.m: Log`
`...`
```

And so on and so forth. Is that possible?

Comment: there's a `__FILE__` macro defining the current file name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use preprocessor macros for that, take a look at this example:

```
NSLog(@"In %s - %s:%d someObject=%@", __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__, someObject);
```

Here's what's available:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1669/_index.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use `__FILE__` macro:

```
NSLog(@"%s",__FILE__ );
```

Which outputs filename:

```
2013-10-16 20:49:17.536 ABC[3637:a0b] /Users/who/where//DeviceViewController.m
```